# Agregar nuevo valor a un campo tipo enum en Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, migration

Estoy trabajando con migraciones en Laravel y tengo una tabla partners que tiene un atributo type de tipo enum con los siguientes valores:

```
$table->enum('type', ['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado', 'transportadora'])->nullable();
```

Lo que necesito es lo siguiente: Crear otra migración para que pueda modificar la tabla partners, agregandole un valor mas al enum para que en la base de datos quede de la siguiente manera:

```
['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado', 'transportadora', 'nuevo_dato']
```

Lo que hasta ahora intenté fue lo siguiente:

```
Schema::table('partners', function ($table) {            
         DB::statement("ALTER COLUMN 'type' ADD VALUE 'nuevo_dato' AFTER 'cliente'");
});
```

Y también intenté:

```
Schema::table('partners', function ($table) {    
      $table->enum('type', ['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado', 'transportadora', 'nuevo_dato'])->change();
});
```

Y...

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE 'partners' MODIFY COLUMN 'type' enum('nuevo_dato') NOT NULL AFTER `transportadora`");
```

Sin llegar al resultado esperado. Les agradecería mucho si me ayudaran con esto.
(PD: estoy usando PostgreSQL)

Comment: ya estas en produccion?

Comment: Si Maru, es un proyecto en producción. Necesito mucho resolver ese problema ya que mi tabla está cargada y no quiero eliminar sus datos.

Comment: hola @MarianoC1993 te comento que cuando una pregunta recibe una respuesta que resuelve el problema, no se le coloca solucionado al título, debes aceptar la respuesta dando click en la palomita que esta a la izquierda, como en este caso Maru Amallo te ayudó por favor revisa el [tour]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la documentación explica como hacer las modificaciones usando `doctrine/dbal` ([Modifying Columns](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/migrations#modifying-columns)) pero aclara que no está soportado para columnas de tipo `enum`.

Particularmente yo trato de evitar las columnas de tipo enum y manejar las opciones desde la aplicación, pero se me ocurre una forma de solucionar tu problema que aunque sean algunos pasos debería resolver tu problema.

**1º Hacé un backup de la base de datos.**

***En la migración***

```
public function up()
{
    // Generá una nueva columna igual a `type`
    Schema::table('partners', function ($table) {    
          $table->enum('type2', ['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado', 'transportadora'])->nullable();
    });

    // Copiá los datos de la columna `type` a la columna `type2` 
    \DB::raw('UPDATE `partners` SET type2=type');

    // Eliminá la columna `type` y volvé a generarla con la nueva definición
    Schema::table('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn(['type']);
        $table->enum('type', ['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado', 'transportadora', 'nuevo_dato']);
    });

    // Volvé a copiar los datos  
    \DB::raw('UPDATE `partners` SET type=type2'); 

    // y luego eliminá la columna `type2` 
    Schema::table('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropColumn([type2']);
    });
}
```

La verdad es que jamás hice algo así pero debería funcionar. Espero tu comentario y recordá REALIZAR UN BACKUP de la BD ANTES de hacer cualquier cosa, sobre todo si estás en producción. Te recomiendo clonar la base en tu entorno local y correr la migración y verificar que funcione entes de correr la migración en produccion.

Comment: Ya probé utilizando doctrine/dbal y no logré lo que quería, estaré probando el método que me mostraste, no imaginé que se podría hacer eso, gracias por tu tiempo, te estaré avisando si resuelvo el problema, muchas gracias.

Comment: dale, cualquier cosa por acá ando.
En la documentación en carteles rojos aclara que no soporta las columnas de tipo `enum` de ahí tu problema. Y si, se puede usar `\DB` en las migraciones. No es lo ideal ya que tenemos los seeders, factories, etc pero es una herramienta muy potente que podemos usar ante estas situaciones.

Comment: Perfecto, muchisimas gracias por tu tiempo, hasta luego.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias Maru, tu código me fue de gran ayuda! Logré solucionar mi problema, gracias por tu tiempo!

Comment: Genial! Me alegro mucho haber sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

El problema con los `enum` es que crean un *constraint* en nuestra tabla que nos limita a usar solo los casos definidos previamente.
Por eso, lo primero que debemos hacer es eliminar la restricción:

```
 DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchases DROP CONSTRAINT purchases_ref_check");
```

Definimos los nuevos datos que queremos incluir en el `enum`

```
$types = ['single', 'monthly', 'biannual', 'amount', 'other'];
$result = join(', ', array_map(function( $value ) { 
    return sprintf("'%s'::character varying", $value); 
}, $types));
```

Volvermos a crear la *constraint*

```
DB::statement("ALTER TABLE purchases 
    add CONSTRAINT purchases_ref_check 
    CHECK (ref::text = ANY (ARRAY[$result]::text[]))"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es usar el método change() en la migración:

```
Schema::table('partners', function (Blueprint $table) {            
         $table->enum('type', ['cliente', 'proveedor', 'empleado',
'transportadora', 'nuevo_valor'])->nullable()->change(); 
});
```